# How to return a vector of the up-to-now minimum of a numeric vector?

Tags: r

I have the following vector, which consists of times in seconds:

```
times <- c(93.813, 89.662, 89.246, 88.641, 88.759, 89.034, 88.783, 88.651, 88.664, 89.028, 88.784, 88.633, 88.616, 88.300, 88.217, 87.954, 88.377, 88.203,
87.836, 87.832, 87.815, 88.514, 88.637, 88.496, 87.338, 87.450, 87.638, 87.511, 87.547, 87.240, 87.235, 87.266, 87.362, 87.457, 87.376, 87.465,
87.108, 87.358, 87.229, 87.273, 87.043, 86.739, 87.397, 87.540, 87.435, 87.448, 87.098, 87.184, 87.071, 87.238, 86.890, 87.898, 86.983, 86.540,
86.830, 86.610, 85.580, 86.627)
```

And I'm looking to return another vector that would be the "best minimum" up to that element. So the result would be:

```
c(93.813, 89.662, 89.246, 88.641, 88.641, 88.641, 88.641, ...)
```

and so on until a smaller time occurs. I've been playing with `lag`, like so:

```
ifelse(times < lag(times), times, lag(times))
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you after `cummin` (i.e. the cumulative minima of a `vector`)?

```
cummin(times)
# [1] 93.813 89.662 89.246 88.641 88.641 88.641 88.641 88.641 88.641 88.641
#[11] 88.641 88.633 88.616 88.300 88.217 87.954 87.954 87.954 87.836 87.832
#[21] 87.815 87.815 87.815 87.815 87.338 87.338 87.338 87.338 87.338 87.240
#[31] 87.235 87.235 87.235 87.235 87.235 87.235 87.108 87.108 87.108 87.108
#[41] 87.043 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739
#[51] 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.540 86.540 86.540 85.580 85.580
```

Comment: This is the worst thing sometimes - running into this stumbling block and completely forgetting the existence of that function. Thanks!

Comment: Been there many times myself @Phil ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone can suggest a more elegant solution, however a solution that works is the following:

```
current = NULL
min.vec = NULL

for(i in 1:length(times)){
  current = c(current, times[i])
  min.vec = c(min.vec, min(current))
}

> min.vec
 [1] 93.813 89.662 89.246 88.641 88.641 88.641 88.641 88.641 88.641
[10] 88.641 88.641 88.633 88.616 88.300 88.217 87.954 87.954 87.954
[19] 87.836 87.832 87.815 87.815 87.815 87.815 87.338 87.338 87.338
[28] 87.338 87.338 87.240 87.235 87.235 87.235 87.235 87.235 87.235
[37] 87.108 87.108 87.108 87.108 87.043 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739
[46] 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.739 86.540
[55] 86.540 86.540 85.580 85.580
```

Comment: *"Perhaps someone can suggest a more elegant solution"* Well, you are already showing the more elegant solution yourself: `cummin(times)`. For fun you should run a `microbenchmark` analysis to see how the `for` loop is roughly four orders of magnitude (that's 10,000 times !!) slower. Growing vectors dynamically in a loop is *very* inefficient in R.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, that was an error, I compared my solution to the one given and accidentally left it in. thanks for mentioning it.